# Git and Terminal Commands not Working in Mavericks

Tags: macos, git, terminal, osx-mavericks

I have two problems:

1. Git is not working although it is installed. Mavericks pops up a window and suggests to install Xcode (I don't want to): "The 'git' command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install it now?"
2. Sometimes even basic commands such as "ls" don't work. "-bash: ls: command not found". However, after inserting the command " . /etc/profile" it works for a while.

My ~/.bash_profile:

```
   export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH 
   export PATH=/usr/local/mongodb/bin
   ### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
   export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

I'm very new to this. Please be aware while helping out.;) Your help is highly appreciated.
Amir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your PATH in this line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mongodb/bin
```

it should be:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mongodb/bin:$PATH
```

Then if you are using OSX I strongly suggest that you use Homebrew http://brew.sh/ which is a package manager (like linux) for mac.

If you are developing on Mac, the command line tools are (almost) required for C/C++/ObjC dev. You can download them without XCode but it is not recommended. Homebrew will need them to build the software for your platform.

To download them go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
Note, you'll need a developer account (it is free)

[image: Xcode command line tools]

Once you have installed homebrew it is easy to have access to the latest software e.g:

```
brew install git
brew install mongodb
etc.
```

You don't have to manage and download the packages by hand. Very handy !

Comment: Thx a bunch! Finally I grasp this homebrew thing.

Best,
Amir

Answer (score 2):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH 
export PATH=/usr/local/mongodb/bin
```

That second `export` overwrites `PATH` completely and sets it to the mongodb directory only. You need to append (or prepend) to `PATH`, not overwrite it.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/mongodb/bin:$PATH"
...
```

Comment: Thx for your help! Appreciated!